# Adding the current date as selected within custom widget

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have created a custom widget that will hold Date + Time with a select option.
Now each Month, day, year, hours and minutes have its own select box.

I have tried many different ways to get these select boxes to automatically have the days date and current time within them. Is this Evan possible with the way i have wrote the custom widget?

Bellow is the class to initialise the form,

```
from widgets import SelectDateTimeWidget
class CreateEvent(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['title', 'start', 'end', 'description', 'category']
        widgets = {

            'start': SelectDateTimeWidget(date_format= '%d/%m/%Y'),
            'end': SelectDateTimeWidget(date_format= '%d/%m/%Y')
        }
```

The custom widget(holds another custom widget):

```
class SelectDateTimeWidget(forms.MultiWidget):
    supports_microseconds = False

    def __init__(self, attrs=None, date_format=None, time_format=None):
        widgets = (SelectDateWidget(empty_label=( "Year", "Month", "Day")),
                   SelectTimeWidget(use_seconds=False))
        super(SelectDateTimeWidget, self).__init__(widgets, attrs)

    def decompress(self, value):
        if value:
            value = to_current_timezone(value)
            return [value.date(), value.time().replace(microsecond=0)]
        return [None, None]

    def subwidgets(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        if self.is_localized:
            for widget in self.widgets:
                widget.is_localized = self.is_localized
        # value is a list of values, each corresponding to a widget
        # in self.widgets.
        if not isinstance(value, list):
            value = self.decompress(value)
        output = []
        final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs)
        id_ = final_attrs.get('id')
        for i, widget in enumerate(self.widgets):
            try:
                widget_value = value[i]
            except IndexError:
                widget_value = None
            if id_:
                final_attrs = dict(final_attrs, id='%s_%s' % (id_, i))
            output.append(widget.render(name + '_%s' % i, widget_value, final_attrs))
        return output
```

Is there anyway i can set the the value to the current date?

Thanks J

Answer (score 0):

From Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/widgets/):

> A widget is Django’s representation of an HTML input element.The widget handles the rendering of the HTML, and the extraction of data from a GET/POST dictionary that corresponds to the widget.

So, adding a default value, like current date is not widget's purpose. It's what form fields are for. If you want to add a default value to your form then it's better to do it via form field, like this:

```
your_field = forms.DateField(initial=datetime.date.today)
# in case of modelForm, just override the fields you need.
```

or when you initialise the form

```
form = CreateEvent(
    initial={'start': datetime.datetime.now, 'end': datetime.datetime.now}
)
```

Related docs: [providing initial values to form field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#initial) and [providing initial values to modelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values)